# What physical law(s) are violated by two masses occupying the same space at the same time?

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics

The two masses have equal mass and equal volume. I think the 2nd law of thermo is violated (because there are less ways to arrange a single mass in space than two), but what other laws could be violated? Specifically, does it violate conservation of mass? And if it does, how exactly is the law violated?

Comment: Two masses of gas can certainly occupy the same space, although the resulting pressure will be higher.

Comment: Nothing prevents the entropy of a system from decreasing.  What's a problem is if you expect to to happen frequently without an external input of energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classicaly speaking, this isn't possible; although we say in certain instances that they can. As Newton pointed out, matter is thought of as impermeable and infinitely hard.

Quantum mechanically, we think of states, and here bosons can occupy the same states, whereas fermions obey the Pauli exlusion principle, and hence cannot occupy the same state. Now matter is made up of fermions rather than bosons, hence even Quantum Mechanically, matter cannot occupy the same space.

Comment: Two Higgs bosons should be able to be in the same place.